# How can I create a read-only realm object?

Tags: android, realm

Suppose I have 2 realm files in my android app, A and B. A is encrypted, B is not. I query realm A on UI Thread and get a realm object with a bunch of String attributes. Now based on these attributes I need to update an object in realm B using the `executeTransaction` to avoid doing it in the UI Thread. The execute method gives me a reference to a realm B instance but I would also need to open realm A because I can't share the previous object with this thread. Since realm A is encrypted I think opening and closing it in the transaction might be a bit slow. Wouldn't it be faster to make a read only copy of the realm object and use that in the transaction? It would be something like this:

```
RealmObject var1 = realmA.where(SensibleData.class).findFirst();
final ReadOnlyObject myReadOnlyObject = copyRealmObject(var1);
realmB.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
    //use myReadOnlyObject to decide how to update RealmObjects
    }
});
```

Would this be a good solution to my problem? What would be a good way of implementing `copyRealmObject` to avoid having memory issues with realm? More specifically, what would be the best way of copying strings? Maybe something like

```
copiedAttribute = new String(realmObject.getSomeStringAttribute());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the `Realm.executeTransaction(Realm.Transaction transaction)` you called is a sync version. It will run in the caller's thread. You need to call `executeTransaction(Realm.Transaction transaction, Realm.Transaction.Callback callback)` for the async one. See [doc of `Realm.executeTransaction`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#executeTransaction-io.realm.Realm.Transaction-).

For your case, you can:

1. Just open the encryption Realm in the transaction, I don't expect it to be slow :) But it will add a few lines of code for opening/closing/query the object.
2. Use `Realm.copyFromRealm`. It will deattach the RealmObject from Realm to make it standalone and can be passed through thread. Although it is not read only, it would be quite handy for you user case. See [doc or `Realm.copyFromRealm`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#copyFromRealm-E-)

---- For the copying `String` question

I think you never need to copy a `String`, since Strings are immutable. You should just use the String returned by getters.